# Github Actions with Jest Suddenly Stopped

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, github-actions

I registered test-coverage ci in github actions

```
name: TEST-COVERAGE

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Nest.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Set up Node_modules
        run: |
          cd ./client
          rm -rf node_modules
          yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache
          cd ..
          cd ./server/gateway
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci
          cd ../services/core
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci
          cd ../auth
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci
          cd ../ticket
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci

      - name: Run Test Coverage
        run: |
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci
          npm run coveralls

      - name: Coveralls
        uses: coverallsapp/github-action@master
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I passed all the test cases with jest, and while executing it, a situation occurred where the Github action suddenly stopped. Even locally, the test code passes and does not emit an error message, but it stops without any output, so it cannot be solved.

`Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Below is my Current Directory

- client
- server

  - gateway
  - auth
  - core
  - ticket

At first, it seemed to be a Github action memory leak, so when I changed the npm install command to npm ci, it ran fine. However, as we added and expanded new features, npm ci encountered the same problem.

- https://github.com/boostcampwm-2022/web03-FanUP/actions/runs/3521371482/jobs/5903147717
- This is github actions result

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "coverage": "jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage --forceExit",
    "coveralls": "jest --coverage --detectOpenHandles --forceExit  && coveralls < ./coverage/lcov.info"
  },
```